# Confusion with recursion

Tags: algorithm, recursion

Suppose I have a recursion with the equation: `T(n)= T(n-2) + c` .. This means that we are breaking the problem size consequently by a factor of 2 and the order of this algorithm is O(n) which is right! Now, Suppose my equation becomes, `T(n)= T(n-2)+cn` .. why does the order becomes n2 (to the power of 2) ? I don't want any recursion tree method or any other method to prove it becomes n2 .. Just tell me what does `c` and `cn` make the difference here ?

Comment: You can prove it by expanding the expression to T(0).

Comment: Thats the first thing i said .. i dont want to prove it.. tell me what difference c and cn make here ? :)

Comment: programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: All these boils down to proving or applying theorem. You can't say anything without proving it.

Comment: @nhahtdh: agree. for this reason I voted to close

Comment: i read somewhere on the internet, T(n)=T(n-1)+c means that we are doing constant amount of work to break the problem .. and T(n)=T(n-1)+cn means we are doing cn work to break the sub problem .. now what does work done imply here in layman terms! ??

Comment: @KarolyHorvath : eh!? voted to close .. ! huh, if you are so intelligent answer what does work done means in here!?

Comment: @user975234: work means you have to *think*. nobody else can do that for you

Comment: yeah, i guess other people don't have the Capability to think! so may be i'll have to!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Just tell me what does c and cn make the difference here ?

It means, that the additional work always increases by one `c` (or two in the case of `T(n -2) + cn`):

> T(n) = T(n-1) + c

If the problem size increases by one, the additional work you need to put in is `c`, which is constant.

> T(n) = T(n-1) + cn

If the problem size increases by one, the additional work you need to put in is one more `c` than when you last increased the problem size by one.

I.e. suppose you increased the problem size from `n` to `n + 1`, which added `10c` of additional work. When you now increase the problem size from `n + 1` to `n + 2`, you will need to add an additional `11c` of work.

We end up with this series:

```
d + c + 2c + 3c + 4c + 5c + ...
```

Comment: can we create an analogy for the work done ? I mean something practical which relates to work done in this case?

Comment: @user975234 I just used "work" instead of running time because it's shorter ;) Since such exercises are usually about how much time an algorithm takes, I suppose you could say `time`.